# Providing javascript code to users, instead of showing entire code for the web application?

Tags: javascript, php

This question might not be suitable for this website and I am only asking this for information purposes..

So, please let me know if this is not suitable and I will delete it.

I have created a `web application` using `PHP` and `Javascript`.

what I want to do is to find a way to turn the entire thing into a small javascript code so I only give that piece of javascript code to the users and they can copy and paste it in their website in order to be able to use the application on their own website without being able to edit the contents of it!

could someone please advise on this?

Again, please let me know if this question is not suitable for this site and I will delete it.

Comment: Like a widget type this? perhaps an iframe will work for you. Any yes,  as it stands this question is not suitable - its far too generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this, make it available as an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) widget (which could theoretically be injected through javascript) or make a cross-domain API with which the javascript would interface. From the sound of it going down the iframe route sounds most sensible, although it does come with a [clickjacking vulnirability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking).